# Similar to Jad file in J2ME & BlackBerry, exist in Android?

Tags: java, android

Similar to jad entries in J2ME, 
is there any such provision in android?

Comment: Please add information about the particular jad functionality you are looking for in Android

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Jad file for J2ME and Blackberry is there for a) app permissions, b) app name c)key-value pairs that are used in the app.

For a) and b) in Android we use AndroidManifest.xml. For c) we can use a .properties file or xml in the apk. Note that we can modify Jad file after compilation for modifying key-value pairs, but we cant do the same with Android. Atleast we cannot do it manually. We can programmtically modify values in the properties file, say by overwriting them with values sent from server.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand well, you should declare it on AndroidManifest.XML that each application should have.

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply, but I just wanted to add one url which is not same across all the app instance.so please suggest any legitimate way to do so.